# Wordpress custom taxonomy template not working

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates

I installed theCartPress plugin and it created tcp_product_category taxonomy for tcp_product post type. I created a page with custom template [to list all the product categories](http://palivonas.lt/test/islosaitis/catalogue).

I can use `single-tcp_product.php`, but `taxonomy-tcp_product_category.php` doesn't work. I tried removing `tcp_` (it's rewritten like that), tried everything from template hierarchy. I installed "Reaveal template" plugin and when I visit

> ```
> http://palivonas.lt/test/islosaitis/product_category/spinteles/
> ```

it shows "archive.php". I tried changing code, nothing changes there. I emptied `archive.php`, `category.php`, `index.php`, `page.php` and nothing changed in that link, still shows `"Category Archives: spintelės"` title and list of products. Any ideas?

Don't mind any layout issues, I'm just trying to make it work, then design.

---

*I've been trying to make this work for a few hours now and I give up, I need help.*

Comment: If this is plugin-specific, you're probably going to get better support on the [plugin's support site](http://community.thecartpress.com/forums/).

Comment: No, it's not. Plugin is for cart, buying and other stuff. This is just custom post types. I've ran into this problem before just using custom post types without any plugins, but left it.

Comment: @AndriusPalivonas Just downloaded the plugin. It implements it's own template hierarchy for cart-related taxonomies. There even seems to be an options area for configuring them.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic it's old question, but I'll just let you know, that somewhy that options area didn't change anything for me.